# Can spambots access pages available to only registered, authenticated users?

Tags: security, email, privacy

I have a web application where users register and are activated via an email sent to the email address they supplied.

Then there are pages that are only visible to registered users (non-user access is restricted by checking for a User Object in the session).

On these restricted pages I would like to display a listing that includes the email addresses of other users.

Do I still need to take precautions to obfuscate the email addresses so that they are protected from spam bots and the like? Or is it enough that the page isn't accessible to non-authenticated users?

Edit: The emails on my site are not particularly valuable and it is not a site with very sensitive material. I just don't want the users to be bothered with spam.

Comment: Are the other users expecting that their email addresses will be provided to other members?

Comment: Yes. They are told that their details will be displayed...

Comment: How difficult is it to register? What would keep a spammer from registering an account?

Comment: I was under the impression that email validation also thwarts spammers (non-human) from registering (as well as its other benefits of not allowing users to sign up other users).

Comment: Emails are free. You can get as many as you like at any place on earth, so email registration has no real security effect. (though it somewhat ensures that you deal with a single entity, since no two people can have the same email address unless they share it)

Comment: Then your answer would be that spambots have the same exact access to a "user-only" page as they do to a page that's open to the entire public? They know how to confirm email address (ie: clicking link in email sent to them)?

Comment: They have to do this only one time manually, register account, click confirmation link (could be automated with many email clients) and from there have full access and can use their normal bot. At least that's possible if somebody thinks it's worth his time to do so. Emails as spam targets are not worth that much money I think. But still it's easy and possible.

Comment: Couldn't you just implement a small email like feature where people have a form where they can enter text and select another user as recipient and then your server 'forwards' this text to the email address of this user? Would be much saver and once the contact is made, they can exchange mail directly. Or some kind of 'friend' request where only confirmed people can see such data?

Comment: @thorstenmüller the challenge with such is that unless you do it well, it becomes the delivery method for the spammers and then it looks like *you* are spamming.

Comment: @thorstenmuller Yes. If I determine that there is a risk of the emails being spammed, then I will implement something like this. That is what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: You may want to ask over on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/), those guys should be able to give good advice on whether email registration is enough to deter bots in your case, and what alternatives there are if you need to both show emails and protect privacy.

Comment: email is not enough to deter spambots.  If it was, no registration form would ever contain a captcha.  If you want to avoid spambots, you need some kind of captcha.

Comment: Even captcha is not enough with e-mail confirmation. Like another comment eluded to, spammers will create several accounts manually like any human and just scrape or form spam at will. You are better off creating your own simple messaging system that is internal only and let the users offer their own e-mail addresses manually if they want to go off-site with their communications. This should be a lot simpler to do anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

When handling user data, especially in a format where it will subsequently be visible to others, you are better off taking more precautions against spam. Spambots are getting better and better at harvesting data, and if they identify an easy way to access such data via your site, you're likely to become a target.

Not only is this bad for your users but it's also bad for your site, as frequent bot traffic can put a load on your servers and slow the site down.